# Passing structure with array of unknown size from unmanaged to managed code

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, void-pointers

I have a problem passing void pointer from unmanaged code to managed. There is a function's pointer in .cpp file

```
TESTCALLBACK_FUNCTION testCbFunc;
```

TESTCALLBACK_FUNCTION takes C++ structure

```
typedef void (*TESTCALLBACK_FUNCTION )(TImage image);
struct TImage
{
    int Width;                      //width
    int Height;                     //height
    void *Buf;                      //data buffer
};
```

C# function and structure

```
public void TImageReceived(TImage image)
{
    // logic
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1), Serializable]
public struct TImage
{
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
    public IntPtr Buf;
}
```

*TImageReceived* passed to unmanaged code and when it's called I receive exception.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException

If I passed *NULL* in field Buf from unmanaged code everything will works fine.

I know about MarshalAs atrribute, but the problem is that I cannot use SizeConst because Buf size is always different. But it always has size of Width*Height.

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=???)]
```

How to cast void* from unmanaged to managed code?

Comment: You also can't do much with `void*` in the unmanaged world either without having a mechanism to determine the size.    So how does your unmanaged code determine the size of `Buf`?    is there a calculation based on `Width` and `Height`?   (e.g. perhaps `Buf` is simply a sequence of bytes representing Width*Height?)

Comment: Yes, `Buf` has a size Width*Height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, and assuming that `TImage` from your C++ code maps neatly on to your struct (Warning - if you're using `TImage` from the Borland VCL, then that might not map on as neatly as you're hoping)

> `Buf` has a size Width*Height

Your best option is to use `Marshal.Copy`, for example

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

/* ... */

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TImage 
{
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
    public IntPtr Buf;
}

/* ... */

public void TImageReceived(TImage image)
{
    var length = image.Height * image.Width;
    var bytes = new byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(image.Buf, bytes, 0, length);
}
```

Related:
[Marshalling struct with embedded pointer from C# to unmanaged driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681517/marshalling-struct-with-embedded-pointer-from-c-sharp-to-unmanaged-driver)

...**However**...

If `TImage` belongs to Borland's VCL then I would suggest re-thinking the struct, because it will involve marshalling other data inherited from `TImage`'s base class (Borland's documentation is unclear about the class' layout) - in which case, it would be easier to pass the arguments directly:

```
public void TImageReceived(IntPtr buf, int width, int height)
{
    var length = height * width;
    var bytes = new byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(buf, bytes, 0, length);

    // etc.
}
```