# Finding all uses of a Custom Attribute and retrieving the values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes

I have an MVC4 app with multiple controllers that all inherit from BaseController.  In some of these controllers, I have Actions with a Custom Attribute of PageKey.  Page Key has two properties (Group & Key).

I need a way to get every instance of this attribute in all controllers and access the values.  I also want to not have to modify the code later when I add new controllers or instances of the attribute.

Comment: Are you looking for: "find in files" as text OR some reflection code to get particular attribute on all classes/method in particular assembly OR something else? Please also comment on what do you means in "I want to not have to modify the code later" requirement.

Comment: This would be runtime code.

I would like to find a way to either get all controllers in the application and cycle through them to find all instances of the attribute, or something similar and simpler.  If I add a new controller or an new instance of the attribute at a later date, I don't want to have to add that controller name to a list to cycle through.  It should just get it with the list of all controllers in the app.

Comment: `Assembly.GetTypes`, than `Type.GetMethods` and [GetCustomAttributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268898/how-do-i-getcustomattributes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.

```
var attributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
            .SelectMany(m => m.GetCustomAttributes())
            .Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof(PageKeyAttribute));
```

Thanks to Alexei Levenkov.